# Обрезать картинку по эллипсу

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Есть пример в песочнице - http://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/gXZJf/

```
var clipByName = function (ctx) {
    var clipRect = findByClipName(this.clipName);
    var scaleXTo1 = (1 / this.scaleX);
    var scaleYTo1 = (1 / this.scaleY);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(degToRad(this.angle * -1));
    ctx.scale(scaleXTo1, scaleYTo1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
        clipRect.left - this.left,
        clipRect.top - this.top,
        clipRect.width,
        clipRect.height
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы обрезание картинки было по эллипсу? Мне удалось сделать только по кругу, с помощью *arc*.

P.S в песочнице необходимо включить *Fabric.js*.

Comment: посмотри если рисование эллипса(формула) может тебе помочь в решении этой задачи  https://jsfiddle.net/Smoren/vjrkst4c/

Comment: Да, это помогло, спасибо большое!